# Implementing the below conditional logic through criteria api in hibernate

Tags: hibernate, hql, criteria

I have a pojo class name teedObject
which consists of following properties and getters and setters as shown below

this pojo is mapped to the table named boa_rep_deed through hibernate.

```
class teedObject
{

    private long abcID ;
    private String syncSystem ;
    private String hookId;

    //and consisits of setters and getters

}
```

NoW I want to implement this below query through criteria

```
select abc_id, count(*) from boa_rep_deed where sync_system = ? And hook_id = ? group by abc_id order by abc_id
```

As shown sync_system will be entered by user and also hook_id will also be eneterd by user
please advise how to implement this through criteria

I have come up with the below approach , pls advise

```
List<teedObject> hytlow = null;
        Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(teedObject.class);
        criteria.add(Restrictions.ne("abcID ", abcID));
        criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("syncSystem", syncSystem));
        criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("hookId", hookId));

        hytlow = criteria.list();
```

not still two things are still not happening one is the count thing and the other thing is order by thing , please advise how to achieve both , as I am looking exact replica of this query...

```
select abc_id, count(*) from boa_rep_deed where sync_system = ? And hook_id = ? group by abc_id order by abc_id
```

Comment: What have you tried? Have you read the documentation, which has several examples of similar queries? http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.3/manual/en-US/html_single/#querycriteria-projection

Comment: @JBNizet can you please see my updated post

Comment: order can also be solved like this ...addOrder( Order.asc("abc_id") );

Comment: I posted a link which points to the part of the documentation explaining how to do that. Read it.